# how to communicate with facebook api through appium

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, appium, android-testing

I am writing an android testing program on java using a Web server to send commands to a device and I want to test logging in with different accounts on Facebook.Although I am not able to enter the email and the password to the input boxes.How can i access these fields in order to put email and password and press log in?

Right now i am trying to access the fields like this although it doesn't seem to work.

```
        driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys(email);       //Email adress or phone number
        driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys(psw);                             //password
```

Comment: Is the facebook open as native app or in web browser? What is the capabilities you have setup?

Comment: No the facebook app is not installed in the device.I included the latest jars of selenium(standalone,client and server),and i am using Appium 1.2.4.1 version.The device in which i am testing the app is a Samsung galaxy s3.

Comment: Try using automation-name as selendriod as for I feel facebook app is hybrid app. Specify the apk path in app capability. Then print out how many contexts are coming using code like this (below is c# sample)

foreach(String context in driver.contexts())
{
   if(context.contains("WebView"){
    driver.context = context;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this question is still relevant, but I also tried to login with FB and I could achieve it with this simple code block

```
    find_element_by_name("Continue with Facebook").click(); 
    List<WebElement> textInputs = tags("android.widget.EditText");      
    textInputs.get(0).sendKeys("xxxxx@xxx.com");
    textInputs.get(1).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx");
    find_element_by_acccessibility_id("Log In").click(); 
    find_element_by_name("OK");        
    Thread.sleep(6000);
```

I just searched for the first two appearing "EditText" views and entered some text